# How to use an input with high current amplitude while the lookup tables in model are based on small amplitude values?

Tags: matlab, simulink, lookup-tables, model-fitting, integrator

I am trying to fit a model to some measurements to model a battery. 
Input of my model is current and the output is voltage of battery terminal. 
I am using some 3D lookup tables in my model.

The breakpoints (dimensions) are: SOC (state of charge), temperature, and current amplitude and the table data in the impedance value of battery circuit elements.

The measurements are done using very small values for the current (in range of 2 A). 
After completing the model I am supposed to validate the model using a standard signal for current input that includes very high current amplitudes (in range of 250 A). 
Then comparing the output of my model (voltage) with the one from the measurements using that standard signal for the current.

Now when I try to run the model I get singularity error over one of the integrators. I am sure this is caused by the high amlitude of current as the input, but the problem is that I can not limit the amplitude using e.g. saturation blocks. I also tried to solve the problem with different solvers but could not fix the problem. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this problem?

Please access my files from [here](http://www.files.com/set/53e4c87b71042).

Comment: It would be helpful if you uploaded the diagrams of the various systems you tried and mentioned what seemed to be the problem with each of them.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but since i am new in this forum, i cant upload images, or files becasue i need more reputation.(at least 10! ) So how can I do that now?

Comment: Upload the file(s) to a public file sharing website and link it here?

Comment: please access to my files using the following link:http://www.files.com/set/53e4c87b71042

Comment: Well now that you have 10+ rep, you can go ahead and edit your question and upload whatever you  want to. Generally, people that are moderately interested in answering questions, won't follow external links. So, my advice would be to edit your question with relevant codes and images, so that everything is "seen" here.

Comment: Three questions: What kind of a model are you using? A simple linear combination of three variables (guess not if you see singularities)? Why would you ever want to test your model with something clearly out of scope compared to what you fitted your model with? What "order" is your model, e.i. how many internal parameters are you fitting based on you input?

Comment: Your script fails even at the first line??? `Undefined function or variable 'getSignalWidth'.`

Comment: A general idea - If your model is robust, any input signal should yield a good output. It _might_ not be a Matlab problem.